# List of Figure/Table : Full justify caption

Tags: tocloft

How can I fully justify list of figure/table like the image below ?

I believe it has something to do with `tocloft` configuration, but I cant find relevant things related to justify.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the `tocloft` package. However, it has nothing to do with “justify”: It’s all about left-indents and right-margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\cftsetrmarg{0pt}% <- Set right margin to zero
\renewcommand\cftfigpresnum{\figurename~}% <- Prepend `Figure' in front of number
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{:}% <- Append `:' behind number
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnumb{\hspace{5em}}% <- Add enough space to start caption text
\cftsetindents{figure}{0pt}{0pt}% <- Set left indents to zero
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\section{Blah}
\begin{figure}[!hb]
No thing to see here.
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!hb]
No thing to see here.
\caption[Short caption title]{\blindtext}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image: List of Figures]

---

But why would you want to do this? The first caption in the LoF looks so crowded and you should keep the LoF (and ToC, LoT, etc) clean and concise. Just use short caption title as in the second caption and you don’t need to change many things. I intentionally leave out the customization of the LoT as well as that of the ToC, and strongly encourage you to use short titles.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and example.. I'm looking at my template and saw `\setrmarg`.. Modifying that seems to work as well.. Hopefully it doesn't disturb the whole document.